# Selecting Columns of imported file and copy and paste them to another sheet in non order form

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, columnsorting

1. I made a function to import file and select specific columns of the imported file
2. Then copying these columns to another sheet
3. but i need to paste the columns in non order form for ex: Column B,C to B,C but A to D
   so the final order is B,C,A in B,C,D
4. selecting the function of the each entire column to its last row is working fine separatly but when i merge it with the import file function it does not work and the file is just opened and not closed and the data is not copied too

Code:

```
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Set Ssheet = OpenBook.Worksheets("Default")


'Selecting Destination
Dim DestSheetB As Range
Set DestSheetB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference & Joins").Range("B2")
Dim DestSheetC As Range
Set DestSheetC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference & Joins").Range("C2")
    Dim DestSheetD As Range
    Set DestSheetD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference & Joins").Range("D2")

    'Select LastRow of the imported file
Dim LastRowA As Long
LastRowA = Ssheet.Cells(Ssheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Ssheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowA).Copy Destination:=DestSheetD

Dim LastRowB As Long
LastRowB = Ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Ssheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRowB).Copy Destination:=DestSheetB

Dim LastRowC As Long
LastRowC = Ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Ssheet.Range("C2:C" & LastRowC).Copy Destination:=DestSheetC

      OpenBook.Save
      OpenBook.Close True

End If
```

No error occurs with debug mode, and this is the result
[image]

Comment: Have you debugged, stepped through?

Comment: `LastRowA` should use "A" not "B". `LastRowB` should use "B" not "C". `LastRowC` which you are missing should use "C".

Comment: @SJR the problem is that no error occurs, The Imported file is just opened and not closed and its data is not copied

Comment: @CDP1802 as i told to SJR the same issue too after editing as per your recommandation

Comment: What happens when you step through? There must be more to this because there is a line which closes the workbook.

Comment: @SJR Thank you after restarting excel itself, issue is solved after performing CDP1802 modification